# BigQuery There is a page view, but no product displays within 10 sec of starting the page view

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with BigQuery and I need to get data from Google Analytics. I am trying to make a query for:

1. There is a page view, but no product displays within 10 sec of starting the page view

The site is using standard ecommerce settings.

Here is my variant, but I think there is a mistake here.

```
WITH PageViews AS (
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId,
    hits.type AS hitType,
    hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath,
    hits.time/1000 AS hitTimeInSeconds,
    hits.eventInfo.eventCategory as eventCategory,
    hits.eventInfo.eventAction as eventAction,
    hits.eventInfo.eventLabel as eventLabel

  FROM
    `bq-brandshops.**********.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20230901' AND '20230930'
)
SELECT
  pagePath,
  min(hitTimeInSeconds)
FROM
  PageViews
WHERE
  hitType = 'EVENT' and eventCategory = 'eecommerce'  and eventAction != 'show' and eventLabel != 'impressionsProduct'
GROUP BY
  pagePath
HAVING
  min(hitTimeInSeconds) < 10
```

Maybe u have any idea?